# How to get the rendered height of the grid after databound? ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I have to display the grid (grid A) with multiple rows which has wrapped text. To align the top of the next grid (grid B) below grid A, I need to know the rendered height of the grid A in CODEBEHIND.

Comment: What grid? A Web Forms `GridView`? Something else?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The grid will not itself know what CSS is applied to it on the client side. The height on the client might also depend on the screen resolution and the size of the browser window etc. Only the client will can reliably know the height of the rendered grid/table.

Comment: Yes it is a grid view in Web Forms Application